# Read data from a Json file and save chart to html using Altair

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, altair

I am using altair on a jupyter notebook where I am trying to convert a pandas dataframe to a json file before passing it to Altair chart. I would like to save the final chart as a html file.

```
import altair as alt
alt.renderers.enable('notebook')
alt.data_transformers.enable('json')
from vega_datasets import data

url = 'data.json'
cars = data.cars()
cars.to_json(url, orient='records')

charts1=alt.Chart(url).mark_circle(size=60).encode(
x='Horsepower:Q',
y='Miles_per_Gallon:Q',
color='Cylinders:O',
tooltip=['Name:Q', 'Origin:N', 'Horsepower:Q', 'Miles_per_Gallon:Q']
).interactive()

charts1.save('cars1.html')


charts2=alt.Chart(cars).mark_circle(size=60).encode(
x='Horsepower:Q',
y='Miles_per_Gallon:Q',
color='Cylinders:O',
tooltip=['Name:Q', 'Origin:N', 'Horsepower:Q', 'Miles_per_Gallon:Q']
).interactive()

charts2.save('cars2.html')

charts1 | charts2
```

Both charts1 and charts2 are displayed correctly in jupyter notebook but only cars2.html is displayed properly when I open it in my browser. cars1.html is just an empty white box. Have I got the syntax wrong? I am in python3.6, Altair version: '2.2.2', Jupyter: '4.3.0'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `chart1`, the data exists in a separate file (`data.json`), and that file has to be accessible to the browser in order for the browser to render the data in a chart. If the data file is not accessible (either because it is at the wrong URL, or due to a cross-origin issue) then the result will be a blank chart.

To determine what the issue is, open your browser's javascript console and check what the error is.

For example, if you're viewing your chart from a `file://` URL, the data may not be accessible if your browser has strict cross-origin policies. Try viewing the file via a local webserver instead (you can use `python -m http.server`).